# Need space between two numbers in VB code

Tags: vb.net

I have this number in my form:

[image]

I'm trying to put a space between the two numbers (345 and 346).

This is what I have so far:

```
For i = 1 To s 
    m = be(i - 1) 
    tex = tex & be(i - 1) & 
Next i 
ListBox1.Items.Add(tex)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: im using code For i = 1 To s m = be(i - 1)
            tex = tex & be(i - 1) & 
        Next i
        ListBox1.Items.Add(tex)

Comment: There's not anywhere close to enough detail yet to answer this. Can you explain more what each of those variables are for? Do this by _editing the original question!_

Comment: It looks like your code hasn't appeared correctly in the question, but if you want to add a space then you can concatenate that in too, something like `tex = tex & " " & be(i - 1)`.

Comment: Your code makes little sense as it is but I suspect that what you want is `ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Join(" ", be))`. Just that and nothing else, i.e. get rid of the loop altogether.

Comment: My code' s = k.Geometry.GetNoOfSelectedBeams
        ReDim be(s)
        k.Geometry.GetSelectedBeams(be)
        For i = 1 To s
            m = be(i - 1)
            tex = tex & be(i - 1) & 
        Next i
        ListBox1.Items.Add(tex)
    End Sub'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, your question is quite vague, however ...

If the two numbers were originally one (346345) and will always be 6 digits split into two 3-digit numbers:

```
Dim num As Integer = 346345
Dim tex As String = $"{num.ToString().Substring(0, 3)} {num.ToString().Substring(3, 3)}"
```

or

```
Dim num As Integer = 346345
Dim tex As String = num.ToString()
tex = $"{tex.Substring(0, 3)} {tex.Substring(3, 3)}"
```

If the numbers are separate (346 and 345, etc):

```
Dim num1 As Integer = 346
Dim num2 As Integer = 345
Dim tex As String = $"{num1.ToString()} {num2.ToString()}"
```

**Update**: With type interpolation there is no need to cast `Integer` to `String`, so the last line above can be simplified to:

```
Dim tex As String = $"{num1} {num2}"
```